# Sort a dictionary by value

Tags: vb.net, sorting, dictionary

i was searching for a simple solution that i can use in sorting a dictionary by value, and i was not content with what i found, so i made up these two functions for sorting a dictionary ascending and descending. I do not assume that they are perfect, so improvements are welcomed. They are written in VB.Net and use an intermediary dictionary.

```
 Public Function SortDictionaryAsc(ByVal dict As Dictionary(Of Long, Decimal)) As Dictionary(Of Long, Decimal)
    Dim final As New Dictionary(Of Long, Decimal)
    Dim min As Decimal = dict.Values.ToList.Max
    Dim key As Long
    Do
        min = dict.Values.Max + 1
        For Each x In dict.Keys
            If dict(x) < min Then
                min = dict(x)
                key = x
            End If
        Next
        final.Add(key, min)
        dict.Remove(key)
    Loop While dict.Keys.Count > 0
    Return final
End Function

Public Function SortDictionaryDesc(ByVal dict As Dictionary(Of Long, Decimal)) As Dictionary(Of Long, Decimal)
    Dim final As New Dictionary(Of Long, Decimal)
    Dim max As Decimal = 0
    Dim prev As Decimal = 0
    Dim key As Long
    Do While dict.Keys.Count - 1 > 0
        For Each x In dict.Keys
            If dict(x) > max Then
                max = dict(x)
                key = x
            End If
        Next
        final.Add(key, max)
        dict.Remove(key)
        max = 0
    Loop
    Return final
End Function
```

Comment: Asking for code review of existing code. No issue or error is mentioned about the code posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better use LINQ for that.
Look at example

```
    ' Create an array of Pet objects.
    Dim pets() As Pet = {New Pet With {.Name = "Barley", .Age = 8}, _
                         New Pet With {.Name = "Boots", .Age = 4}, _
                         New Pet With {.Name = "Whiskers", .Age = 1}}

    ' Order the Pet objects by their Age property.
    Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Pet) = _
        pets.OrderBy(Function(pet) pet.Age)
```

[More details on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx#Y1026)

Comment: Just want to add that if you want to order descending use `pets.OrderByDescending`

Answer (score 0):

For best performance you can use LINQ to object http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb397919.aspx

An example of sorting, using one of your function and sorting by key is:

```
Public Function SortDictionaryAsc(ByVal dict As Dictionary(Of Long, Decimal)) As     Dictionary(Of Long, Decimal)       
    Dim final = From key In dict.Keys Order By key Ascending Select key
End Sub
```